# Why DOCTYPE destroy my page?

Tags: html, css, doctype

yes the reply is I'm a very bad css coder but I really need to understand that, I created a page without using any doctype and the things goes whell in IE, FF and Chrome, except one or two very little thing, then I decided to add a doctype to see, but everything is displayed anyhow.

Google doesn't help me...

The page without doctype: http://commenttrouver.com/test/indexwithout.php

And with : http://commenttrouver.com/test/index.php

Thank you

Comment: Because with DOCTYPE browsers follow the standard. Quick look at you HTML reveals a lot of errors. At least sizes in CSS must have units, so `width:800` is invalid and must be `width:800px` and so on.

Comment: Doctype tells the browsers how to render the page, without doctype, the browser has to guess how to do it. If you had errors then the browser will fix them but with a doctype it won't.

Comment: The start tag for the HTML element is entirely optional.

Answer (score 7):

Including (most) Doctypes, triggers Standards mode in browsers.

They stop emulating the bugs that appeared in older versions of browsers and more rigorously apply the standards (such as the requirement to treat a CSS length without a unit as "invalid and to be ignored" instead of "pixels").

- [Validate your HTML](http://validator.w3.org/).
- [Validate your CSS](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/).

Then worry about why anything still broken is broken.

Comment: this is absolutely correct. the problem is not the doctype but your css/html. you should always use doctype.

Comment: Thank you in fact I already tried to validate my css but didn't understand want it said about the widths and heights